# Deleting all files except the ones which match a regex

Tags: regex, find

I have a set of images generated by wordpress, and I need to get rid of them (example of one generated set):

- Y3A6036-1-150x150.jpg
- Y3A6036-1-180x138.jpg
- Y3A6036-1-220x161.jpg
- Y3A6036-1-300x200.jpg
- Y3A6036-1-300x214.jpg
- Y3A6036-1-460x295.jpg
- Y3A6036-1-540x272.jpg
- Y3A6036-1-700x441.jpg
- Y3A6036-1-768x512.jpg
- Y3A6036-1-940x400.jpg
- Y3A6036-1-1024x683.jpg
- Y3A6036-1.jpg

But I need to keep the following (the last two in this case):

- Y3A6036-1-1024x683.jpg
- Y3A6036-1.jpg

I am trying to do that using:

```
find /myPathToImages -type f -name '*[0-9]x*[0-9].jpg' -delete
```

But I also get rid of the 1024x683 version. How can I filter it out?

UPDATE:

The regex must keep into account also a vertical image, something like this:

- VERTICAL-1-683x1024.jpg
- VERTICAL-1.jpg

The logical rule is deleting all the images except the original ones and the cropped ones having either width or height = 1024

Comment: try something like that : `find /myPathToImages -type f -name '*[0-9]{3}x[0-9]{3}.jpg' -delete`

Comment: If you can't use `{3}` just use : `find /myPathToImages -type f -name '*[0-9][0-9][0-9]x[0-9][0-9][0-9].jpg' -delete`

Comment: isn't it easier to just `cd /myPathToImages; rm *-???x*`?

Comment: oh I see, that is super smart... this actually save the vertical version of the image (683x1024), thank you

Comment: I create an answer, then you can validate / upvote it ^^

Comment: sidyll you are right, but I need to consider also the vertical image, I will update the post to make it clearer

Comment: Actually the right behaviour is using a stricter version of your command: rm *-???x???.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Why make it harder than it is? You obviously have a way of finding the images you want to keep. Move them to a separate directory. If needed, do it automatically with something like this:

```
mkdir keep
for file in $(ls | grep <regex>); do mv $file keep; done
rm *
mv keep/* .
rm -rf keep
```

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but it works and the general idea is very versatile.

Comment: **Be careful** posting answers with  `rm *`, if something is wrong with the script, you may end-up having a bad day...

Answer (score 0):

There's a pattern on the filenames to delete, they all have **3digits x 3digits** , based on that, you can use :

```
.*-[0-9]{3}x[0-9]{3}\.jpg
```

---

[Regex Demo and Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/3JDMJk/1)

Answer (score 0):

Juste use this one :

```
find /myPathToImages -type f -name '*-[0-9]{3}x[0-9]{3}.jpg' -delete
```

This will delete all image that looks like that 
3 Digit x 3 Digit.

As @Pedro Lobito point out, you need to add `-` before the pattern in order to not match 4 Digit length. Cause due to the `*` It would have considered : 
`*` followed by 3 digit.